# How do I stopPropagation when changing an event inside an event?

Tags: javascript

So I have got the following javascript code:

```
function showSearch() {
    var ev = new Event("onkeydown");
    ev.keyCode = 13;
    document.getElementById("search").onclick = search(ev);
}
```

The function `showSearch()` is called in the `onclick`-event of the Element `#search`. So when assigning the new event, the new one triggers immediately.

I want to prevent that using `stopPropagation()`.

How do I do that? How else could I solve this?

Comment: Does calling `search` return a function?

Comment: `function search(key) {
            if (key.keyCode === 13) {
                window.open("/search/?q=" + searchtext.value, "_self");
            }
        }`
This is the `search` function

Comment: replace `document.getElementById("search").onclick = search(ev)` with `document.getElementById("search").onclick = function search(key){.. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` accepts a *function* as a parameter - you're providing it `undefined` (the result of `showSearch()` ; your current `showSearch()`, being a function call, executes immediately. Assign `onclick` a function instead of a function call:

```js
document.getElementById("search").onclick = showSearch;
const search = () => console.log('searching');
function showSearch() {
    var ev = new Event("onkeydown");
    ev.keyCode = 13;
    document.getElementById("search").onclick = () => search(ev);
}
```

```html
<div id="search">text</div>
```

But using `on`-handlers is pretty bad practice. It would be better to add an event listener instead:

```js
const searchDiv = document.getElementById("search");
searchDiv.addEventListener('click', showSearch);
const search = () => console.log('searching');
function showSearch() {
    var ev = new Event("onkeydown");
    ev.keyCode = 13;
    searchDiv.removeEventListener('click', showSearch);
    searchDiv.addEventListener('click', () => search(ev));
}
```

```html
<div id="search">text</div>
```

Comment: Why is using `on`-handlers a bad practice? Do you have some reference?